# POST returns 400 after executing OnPost() successfully (RazorPages)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using RazorPages in asp.net core.

When I create a post request to my RazorPage using jQuery/Ajax, the OnPost() method runs without errors, and the response status code is set to 200.

```cs
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

In the Chrome console, my request has returned an error code 400 with message "Failed to load resource". The link to the source of the error leads me to [VM6.js](https://paste.mod.gg/izidofequy.js), line 38.

[image: Screenshot of VM6.js]

Similar code works on another RazorPage, so I thought that it could be trying to render my page (.cshtml) and erroring.  I proved this theory wrong by outputting to the console when the cshtml file is loaded and I did not get this output when making the POST request.

Here is the Javascript which is shared by both the working and broken page for submitting my form:

```js
$("[name|='form']").submit(function() {
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function() {
            $("#success").toast("show");
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 429) {
                $("#ratelimit").toast("show");
            } else {
                $("#error").toast("show");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

How can I ensure that my webserver returns code 200 instead of 400?

Comment: What error message is reported in the response body?

Comment: @Phil there is no response body returned by the server, unless I'm mistaken. The response header "content-length" is 0.

Comment: Ok, so what error message is reported in your server-side logging? A 400 means the request is bad. This can be produced by trying to marshal HTTP request data as objects like `Guid` or `DateTime` when the data itself does not meet the requirements

Comment: @Phil I breakpointed at the top of my OnPost() method and stepped through it to the end. It all ran successfully, including the parsing of data from the form. This is why I'm confused about the web server returning 400 because from the server-side it all appears to be running without any problems. There are also no errors in the Kestral output or the visual studio "Output" tab.

Comment: Hold on, I found what's happening! While trying to solve my problem I managed to mess up the form's posting, so my OnPost method wasn't called. After reverting what I did, it now executes OnPost again. But it also tries to load my page's .cshtml file, which throws a null reference exception because some ViewData wasn't set because OnGet() wasn't called beforehand. This results in error 500. I fixed it by returning at the top of my cshtml if the ViewData in question is null. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the 400 error, I needed to include method="post" on my form. This means that the verification token is included and an error isn't thrown.

Because my page included C# code which throws an error if the OnGet() method is not called beforehand, this caused a 500 error after every post request, despite the page not being loaded.

I added `if(~~~ == null) return;` at the top of my cshtml and it appears to work now.